# ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo on an env Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, nas, backport

I have a python environment on my NAS. I tried to install the binance library.

I have this error message:

```
 Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/lib
      /usr/local/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ccache/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-wrap-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV8 -O2 -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DSYNO_RUNNING_DSM_BUILD_SYSTEM -g -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fexceptions -Wbidi-chars=ucn -fstack-clash-protection -fPIC -I/volume1/Python/Bot_Binance/env/env_bot_binance/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      error: command '/usr/local/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ccache/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-wrap-gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

After some research on internet, I try the pip install backports.zoneinfo. It gives me the same answer.
I try the  pip install --upgrade pip. I am on the version 24.0
Some people indicate that the issue is link with the Python Version [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-backports-zoneinfo).
My Python version is 3.8.15.

I don't really know what to do now.

Thanks,

Comment: The error looks similar to https://github.com/postlund/pyatv/issues/1717 so the solution should be similar — you need to install `gcc` compiler.

Comment: The solution with pip install --upgrade bitarray==2.3.7 is not working.

Comment: Python 3.12.1 can get you bugfix.